# jQuery ButtonSet Refresh not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, refresh

## HTML

```
<div id="test">    
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="checkall"/><label for="check1">1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" class="checkall"/><label for="check2">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" class="checkall"/><label for="check3">3</label>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" id="selectall" value="Select All">
```

## jQuery

```
$("#test").buttonset();
$("#selectall").button();
    $("#selectall").toggle(
          function () { $("#test .checkall").prop("checked", true).buttonset("refresh"); },
          function () { $("#test .checkall").prop("checked", false).buttonset("refresh"); }
      );
```

I want to select all button is clicked. But it does not change visually. I'd appreciate if you help.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fenerama/zv8e4/

Comment: Did you mean you wanted to change the visual of the Select all button as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant you wanted to change the visual of the Select all button as well, then it might be better to make that a check box as well. 
In any case, the answer by sdepont is correct in the sense you need to use `button` in there and not `buttonset`.

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/x3QY3/1/

HTML :

```
<div id="test">    
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="checkall"/><label for="check1">1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" class="checkall"/><label for="check2">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" class="checkall"/><label for="check3">3</label>
</div>
<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" value="Select All" /><label for="selectall">Select All</label>
```

JQuery:

```
  $("#test").buttonset();
  $("#selectall").button();

$("#selectall").toggle(
      function () { $("#test .checkall").prop("checked", true).button("refresh"); $("#selectall").prop("checked", true).button("refresh");},
      function () { $("#test .checkall").prop("checked", false).button("refresh"); $("#selectall").prop("checked", false).button("refresh");}
  );
```

Comment: sdespont & ryadavilli | 
Answers was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`Buttonset` is not the appropriate method to call in this case. You need to use `button` method instead

http://jsfiddle.net/zv8e4/3/

```
$("#selectall").toggle(
      function () { $("#test .checkall").prop("checked", true).button("refresh"); },
      function () { $("#test .checkall").prop("checked", false).button("refresh"); }
  );
```